# Apply filter on GET /beta/users/<user_id>/chats/getAllMessages fails

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Hello I have a call at the endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/<user_id>/chats/getAllMessages?$filter=lastModifiedDateTime gt 2021-07-18T00:00:00.000Z
```

with the below code:

```
url = '%sbeta/users/%s/chats/getAllMessages?$filter="lastModifiedDateTime gt %sT00:00:00.000Z"' % (ms_api_url, user_id, before7days.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
response = requests.get(url,
                headers = {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % access_token
                }).json()
```

but I am geting the below error:

```
{
  'error': {
    'code': 'BadRequest',
    'message': 'Invalid filter clause',
    'innerError': {
      'date': '2021-07-25T09:04:49',
      'request-id': '590c724f-e161-44de-a8d9-a011dec40b6e',
      'client-request-id': '590c724f-e161-44de-a8d9-a011dec40b6e'
    }
  }
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chats-getallmessages?view=graph-rest-beta#optional-query-parameters), this API supports date range. So to get it to work for you, you need to add a date range by adding a **lt** operator too. Below is an example.

```
users/{user-id | unpn}/chats/getAllMessages?$filter=lastModifiedDateTime gt 2021-07-18T00:00:00.000Z and lastModifiedDateTime lt 2021-07-19T00:00:00.000Z
```

Notice I have added *and lastModifiedDateTime lt 2021-07-19T00:00:00.000Z* to your attached API call.

Comment: Happy to have helped.